# How to get the App Id or Adam of Safari on iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, itunes, identifier

Is there any way that we get the App Id or Adam (iTunes identifier) of mobile Safari on iOS.

Comment: Do you mean app ID or UUID?

Comment: Hi, We require an iTunes identifier (iTunes App ID).

Comment: You want a app ID of particular application when login the Safari on mobile phone?

Comment: Hi There, when we submit an app to the app store, it gives us a unique identifier, for example "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/******/id535******". Here in the link id535****** is called as Adam Id/ iTunes identifier. I need that Id for mobile Safari.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is published, search it on Google -- the number following 'id' at the end of the URL is the Adam ID. Eg. for AirBnb app:

[image]